# C#: I want every letter of a word to begin in a new line

Tags: c#, line, cpu-word, letter

```
using System;

class HelloCSharp
{
     static void Main()
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello C#");
     }
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
H
e
l
l
o 

C
#
```

but every letter should start on a new line

I am new I know but I keep searching and can't find the answer. Should it be something with `Environment.NewLine` ?

Comment: loop through the characters in the string and use `Environment.NewLine` as you guessed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go:

```
string str = "Hello C#"
char[] arr = str.ToCharArray();

foreach (char c in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Comment: Well, that works with those in the BMP at least. Hope you don't get anything outside, nor multi-codepoint ones.

Answer (score 6):

Implementation by **[Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)** method:

```
var text = "Hello C#".ToCharArray();
var textInLines = string.Join("\n", text);

Console.WriteLine(textInLines);
```

Answer (score 5):

Write a function to loop through a string. Like so:

```
void loopThroughString(string loopString)
{
    foreach (char c in loopString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c);
    }
}
```

now you can call this function:

```
loopThroughString("Hello c#");
```

**EDIT**

Of, if you like linq you can turn the string into a List of one-character strings and merge it by adding new lines to between each character and than printing that on the console

```
string myString = "Hello c#";
List<string> characterList = myString.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", characterList));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all but all options that you have given looks a bit complicated. Is not this easier:

```
const string world = "Hello World!";
 for ( int i = 0; i < world.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(world[i]);
    }
```

I am just asking because I have just started learning and is not the most effective and fastest way to write a program the best? I know that they are many ways to make something work.

Answer (score 0):

Real men only use Regular expressions, for everything! :-)

```
string str = "Hello\nC#";
string str2 = Regex.Replace(str, "(.)", "$1\n", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Console.Write(str2);
```

This regular expression search for any one character `(.)` and replace it with the found character plus a `\n` (`$1\n`)

(no, please... it is false... you shouldn't use Regular Expressions in C# unless you are really desperate).

Comment: as the old joke goes - you used a regex to solve a problem. now you have 2 problems.